# cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException:

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber

Hello I am new to cucumber and selenium. I am trying to execute my maven project with multiple cucumber feature files. But when I do following error i am getting.

```
cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException: Duplicate step definitions in test_cases.invalid_login.close_browser() in file:/D:/rakesh/folder/neon%20workspace/com.maven.cucum/target/test-classes/ and test_cases.valid_loign.close_browser() in file:/D:/rakesh/folder/neon%20workspace/com.maven.cucum/target/test-classes/
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeGlue.addStepDefinition(RuntimeGlue.java:33)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:151)
at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:68)
at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:41)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:92)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:70)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:80)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

And feature file is

```
Feature: login page functionality   
  Scenario: invalid login test
    Given open a browser and goto login page
    When enter "test@techved.com" "Phari@9169"
    Then verify invalid credential message
    And close browser
```

And

```
Feature: login page functionlity
  Scenario: valid login test
    Given open a browser and goto login page
    When enter "rakeshm@techved.com" "Phari@9169"
    Then check login user
    And Logout
    And close browser
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states you have defined two step definitions methods in separate classes which are matching the same regular expression - `test_cases.invalid_login.close_browser() & test_cases.valid_loign.close_browser()`.

The close_browser method is defined in 2 separate classes with the same expression to match. All the step definitions in a project are loaded globally no matter if the scenario you are running uses them or not.

You could either remove one of these methods or change the expression in the given, when, then annotation with the same changes in the feature file.

Answer (score 1):

This issue will occur when stepdefinition has same method name in different projects.

Try to change the Given,When,Then in feature and same in step definition.

have face same error and tried the above method and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the solution is to combine the Scenario's and keep 1 feature file for whole project .
if sentence contain same words try to give identical names,if names are same it will consider as 1 and will create 1 method instead of 2 after executing the Runner class. 
Without maven project we can execute multiple feature files.

Comment: You cannot have just one feature file for a giant project.
https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#:~:text=You%20can%20only%20have%20a%20single%20Feature%20in%20a%20.feature%20file.